# Issue with button dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to web coding, but working currently on a small project for a community of mine, where I try to create a small simple website with basic information.

My issue here is I can't get  to work with my dropdown menu, it wont show on hove over or show my dropdown menu, but once I remove button my dropdown menu will work proberly.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* used # is id="" under html code */


/* used . is class="" under html code */


/* Change value inside #navbar, will change style on main menu */

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #732119;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background: #F2CDA0;
  color: #732119;
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* Change value inside navdown, will change style on Dropdown menu */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: #732119;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  min-width: 140px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #732119;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover .dropbtn {
  background: #F2CDA0;
  color: #732119;
}


/* Change value inside this, will change logo on the site */

#img_center {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* Center everything on the side inside <table> */

#table_main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Footer style, customize footer bar here */

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#h2_headertext {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_main">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Main Menu -->
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#forside">Forside</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blivmedlem">Bliv Medlem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#medlemsfordel">Medlemsfordele</a></li>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Information</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Vedtægter</a>
            <a href="#">Regler</a>
            <a href="#">Hvem er vi</a>
            <a href="#">Bestyrelsen</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li><a class="active" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--Center picture of the side -->
      <div id="img_center">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
        <h2 id="h2_headertext">Velkommen</h2>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Copyright 2022</p>
</div>
```

Comment: For starters, you should not use tables for layout. this is a deprecated non-semantic method.

Answer (score 1):

Please study the following model code carefully. It shows the principle of a dropdown menu on CSS . There is literally nothing there. Learn to understand how it works.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.item:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">Hover me!</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="subitem">subitem1</li>
      <li class="subitem">subitem2</li>
      <li class="subitem">subitem3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i think I got it kinda, only one thing I don't get, is why you type menu as class under ul? is that to show that this code an below is menu`?

Comment: @Anon2022 In general, yes, search engines consider this menu layout semantically correct for indexing. This is the best practice.

Comment: I spent alot of time try to understand the code you linked, I have now tried simple add 1 command at time and try to understand what each of one is doing.
Now I have a perfect dropdown that works, but now I have my text reaching outside the box.

Comment: @Anon2022 I think you need to create a new question with this problem and post your new code there. In words it is difficult to understand how to help.